# Detecting when a call is answered - Voice 2.0.0 beta3 for Swift

Tags: swift, twilio

Does anyone know if there is a way to detect and then have a function run when an outgoingCall is answered?

I am using Twilio's Voice 2.0.0 beta3 for Swift.

The framework has functions that run when outgoingCallIsConnecting and when outgoingCallDidConnect, but not when the call is actually answered. It is considered connected as soon as the two devices connect, but that does not mean that the person on the other end actually answered the call.

In the TVOOutgoingCall.h file of the TwilioVoiceClient Framework, it appears that TVOOutgoingCallStatePending is exactly what I need, but I can't figure out how to use it for what I am trying to accomplish.

Any tips on how I can detect when the call is actually answered and have a function run when that is detected?

Thank you in advance!